# Why is my jQuery AJAX second json value periodically undefined?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm making a Chrome extension and grabbing some quote info from wordsAPI. When I hard refresh the tab, sometimes the word will show, but not the definition and I'll get the console error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'. As you see, I tried adding a timeout but it doesn't really help. Wondering how to fix this please. Thanks.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://wordsapiv1.p.rapidapi.com/words/?random=true',
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-RapidAPI-Key", "longAssGUID")
            }, success: function(data){
               $('#word').html("Word:&nbsp;&nbsp;" + data.word);

              if (data.results[0].definition != undefined){
               setTimeout(function() {            
              $('#def').html("Definition:&nbsp;&nbsp;" + 
              data.results[0].definition);
               }, 2000);
             } 
          }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see if your results are defined before using them. It's possible the API isn't giving you the data you expect.

change:

```
if (data.results[0].definition != undefined){
```

to

```
if (data && data.results && data.results[0].definition) {
```